# Spark Structured Streaming dropDuplicates is not working as expected after restarting the application

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming, delta-lake

I'm  connecting to NATS Jetstream to consume the messages and process using Spark Java code. Below is the code snippet

```
private static void sparkNatsTester() {
 
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("spark-with-nats")
                .master("local")
                .config("spark.jars",                                          
            "libs/nats-spark-connector-balanced_2.12-1.1.4.jar,"+"libs/jnats-2.17.1.jar")
                .config("spark.sql.streaming.checkpointLocation","tmp/checkpoint")
                .config("spark.sql.extensions","io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
                .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", 
            "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")
                  .getOrCreate();
        System.out.println("sparkSession : "+ spark);
        Dataset<Row> df = spark.readStream()
                .format("nats")
                .option("nats.host", "localhost")
                .option("nats.port", 4222)
                .option("nats.stream.name", "mystream")
                .option("nats.stream.subjects", "mysubject")
                .option("nats.durable.name", "myconsumer")
                .option("nats.msg.ack.wait.secs", 120)
                .load();
        Dataset<Row> deDuplicatedDf = df.dropDuplicates("dateTime", "content");
        StreamingQuery query;
        try {
            query = deDuplicatedDf.withColumn("date_only", 
                    from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("dateTime"),  "MM/dd/yyyy - HH:mm:ss Z"), "MM/dd/yyyy"))
                    .writeStream()
                    .outputMode("append")
                    .partitionBy("date_only")
                    .format("delta")
                    //.option("checkpointLocation", "tmp/checkpoint")
                    .start("tmp/outputdelta");
            query.awaitTermination();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
```

While spark application is processing the messages, if we stop the spark application in between and after sometime restart the spark application, then messages processed in the last microbatch just before app was stopped will be re processed . I want to avoid processing duplicates so tried adding

```
Dataset<Row> deDuplicatedDf = df.dropDuplicates("dateTime", "content");
```

After adding dropDuplicates as suggested in [streaming-deduplication](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#streaming-deduplication) , app became very very slow and also it's not dropping duplicates. **Please note that duplicate messages will come to the app after restarting the spark application as NATS resends messages which were not acknowledged**. I even tried with using watermark along with dropDuplicates. Still it's not working. 
How to fix this issue ? And is there any better approach to avoid duplicates in Spark structured streaming with Delta Lake as sink?

**UPDATE** :
Issue in more detail

From NATS CLI, I am running bellow command to push 10k messages for testing

```
nats pub newsub --count=10000 "test #{{Count}}"
```

While spark application is processing the messages, stop the spark application and count the number of processed messages in the output folder = **3100 messages.**
As I can see in the tmp\outputdelta_delta_log folder , the last file which got generated before stopping the application contains below :

```
{"commitInfo":{"timestamp":1701081648739,"operation":"STREAMING UPDATE","operationParameters":{"outputMode":"Append","queryId":"193fec24-78ea-4ac0-87af-7b6232e748ff","epochId":"20"},"readVersion":19,"isolationLevel":"Serializable","isBlindAppend":true,"operationMetrics":{"numRemovedFiles":"0","numOutputRows":"100","numOutputBytes":"1753","numAddedFiles":"1"},"engineInfo":"Apache-Spark/3.3.3 Delta-Lake/2.3.0","txnId":"36a435e7-f775-4f80-a637-48a40c23dc87"}}
{"txn":{"appId":"193fec24-78ea-4ac0-87af-7b6232e748ff","version":20,"lastUpdated":1701081648739}}
{"add":{"path":"date_only=11%252F27%252F2023/part-00000-5c9955af-06c7-4da6-991a-2412f033cd38.c000.snappy.parquet","partitionValues":{"date_only":"11/27/2023"},"size":1753,"modificationTime":1701081648739,"dataChange":true,"stats":"{\**"numRecords\":100**,\"minValues\":{\"subject\":\"newsub\",\"dateTime\":\"11/27/2023 - 16:10:16 +0530\",\"content\":\"test #3001\"},\"maxValues\":{\"subject\":\"newsub\",\"dateTime\":\"11/27/2023 - 16:10:16 +0530\",\"content\":\"test #3100\"},\"nullCount\":{\"subject\":0,\"dateTime\":0,\"content\":0}}"}}
```

As you can see this last microbatch had **numRecords = 100** , and contained messages from **test #3001** to **test #3100**

Now I'm restarting the spark application. After it completes processing pending messages from NATS stream ( 10000-3100 = 6900 messages ) if I check the number of processed messages in the output folder = **10100 messages !** It should have been exactly 10000. 100 messages were duplicated.

If I check tmp\outputdelta_delta_log folder for the first file which got generated right after restarting the spark application contains below :

```
{"commitInfo":{"timestamp":1701081772472,"operation":"STREAMING UPDATE","operationParameters":{"outputMode":"Append","queryId":"f8d338e3-9eb2-49a2-96df-2a4c0e368285","epochId":"10"},"readVersion":30,"isolationLevel":"Serializable","isBlindAppend":true,"operationMetrics":{"numRemovedFiles":"0","numOutputRows":"1000","numOutputBytes":"6250","numAddedFiles":"1"},"engineInfo":"Apache-Spark/3.3.3 Delta-Lake/2.3.0","txnId":"d1a5e794-6827-4c3d-bfa0-e1fd9e3474c9"}}
{"txn":{"appId":"f8d338e3-9eb2-49a2-96df-2a4c0e368285","version":10,"lastUpdated":1701081772472}}
{"add":{"path":"date_only=11%252F27%252F2023/part-00000-8e45d89b-6426-43f5-8144-ee826874dcfb.c000.snappy.parquet","partitionValues":{"date_only":"11/27/2023"},"size":6250,"modificationTime":1701081772455,"dataChange":true,"stats":"{\"**numRecords\":1000**,\"minValues\":{\"subject\":\"newsub\",\"dateTime\":\"11/27/2023 - 16:10:16 +0530\",\"content\":\"test #3001\"},\"maxValues\":{\"subject\":\"newsub\",\"dateTime\":\"11/27/2023 - 16:10:16 +0530\",\"content\":\"test #4000\"},\"nullCount\":{\"subject\":0,\"dateTime\":0,\"content\":0}}"}}
```

As you can see in this microbatch **numRecords = 1000** , and contained messages from **test #3001** to **test #4000** .It again started processing from **test #3001** even though #3001 to #3100 messages were processed by the previous microbatch before app was shutdown. Reason might be after those 100 messages were processed and saved in Delta lake, before acknowledgment was sent back to NATS, app got shutdown. So once app was restarted NATS resent those 100 messages again in the new microbatch.
How I can avoid reprocessing and saving these resent messages again in the Delta lake to avoid duplicates.

**UPDATE 2**

```
df.dropDuplicates("dateTime", "content")
```

works fine if I don't stop and restart the spark app ! I tried pushing 100 messages with same content "test" which got triggered at same time by using `nats pub mysubject --count=100 "test"`. It allowed only 1 message and I could see only 1 message got saved in the output Delta Lake ! So looks like dropDuplicates isn't working after I restart the spark app.
**So issue is only when I stop and restart the app, it won't remember earlier messages which was processed before app was restarted** . It will allow duplicate message which was processed before app was shutdown.
So Will it loose saved data/state for finding the duplicates once we stop the spark app ? If So how do we make sure dropDuplicates work even after we stop and restart the application ?

Comment: I see `nats.msg.ack.wait.secs` is 120 secs. If your micro-batch is processed longer than 120secs, then (if I understand documentation properly) those messages will be added to resending even before Spark completes micro-batch. Another option to play with is `nats.msg.fetch.batch.size`

Comment: What is inside `dateTime` - is it user provided or NATS provided? If NATS updates this field when message is added back to the queue, then it could be bad for deduplication. You can try add your own column `df.withColumn("_ts", unix_timestamp())` and then use for watermark and deduplication (it is important to use the same column in both).

Comment: @Alexander Pavlov `dateTime` is attached when I publish the message from NATS CLI and remains same even when the same message was resent ( when there was no acknowledgment within 120 secs) . For example I could see there are 2 messages with same content with dateTime value as `11/30/2023 - 17:38:35 +0530` . I had also increased `nats.msg.ack.wait.secs` and `nats.msg.fetch.batch.size` tested with different values still no luck.

Comment: `nats.msg.fetch.batch.size` - no, this should be decreased if you want to see improvements in your scenario ;)

Comment: @Alexander Pavlov Oh ok :) Any recommended batch size ? Or any reference .

Comment: I would say go extreme and set it 1 to see if it solves problem. If it does, then use bisection between 1 and 100 to find proper settings

Comment: @Alexander Pavlov same issue with 1 as well. I tested with same content without stopping the app and dropDuplicate is working ! So issue is only when I stop and restart the app, it won't remember earlier messages which was processed before app was restarted. Updated the question with this info as well.

Comment: "So issue is only when I stop and restart the app,"  - do you configure checkpoints location in all your test attempts? it is a must for streaming

Comment: @Alexander Pavlov Yes have configured checkpoints location

Answer (score 0):

Probably reason for you seeing duplicates after restart is because you commented out checkpoint location where state is kept between runs. And, probable reason why it is slow is that you are using default state provider which keeps state in JVM and causes Garbage collection runs to happen more frequently.

I would suggest you to try using RocksDB to save state and see if it will improve your performance and experience:

```py
spark.conf.set(
  "spark.sql.streaming.stateStore.providerClass",
  "com.databricks.sql.streaming.state.RocksDBStateStoreProvider")
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Uncommented checkpoint location and used RocksDB to save the state. Still it's allowing duplicates and also app is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use watermarks to create deduplication window. Otherwise, whole (endless) stream is window and

```
df = df.withWatermark("dateTime", "1 hour")
df = df.dropDuplicates("dateTime", "content")
```

2. I suggest deduplicate using hash of the content, otherwise it makes Spark to store too much data
3. "Please note that duplicate messages will come to the app after restarting the spark application as NATS resends messages which were not acknowledged. " - **is not it good thing?**

If you did not commit micro-batch then nothing is saved to destination so you should reprocess mirco-batch, otherwise there will be lost data.

4. "also it's not dropping duplicates" - restarting streaming application does not create duplicates if you write to Delta. Delta is ACID storage and it commits all-or-nothing, it is impossible in this scenario to write part of micro-batch data to the Delta and get the same data again if application is restarted before writing the rest of the micro-batch.

Comment: thanks for the reply . I had tried with watermarks to create deduplication window still same issue. Problem here is the last microbatch which was processed before app was shutdown gets saved in the Delta Lake but acknowledgment wasn't done back to NATS. So after app was restarted NATS resends those messages again in a new microbatch which again gets processed by spark app and again gets saved in the Delta lake. I want to avoid saving these resent messages again in the Delta lake to avoid duplicates. Updating the question with this info as well.

Comment: @VGH I think you should focus your efforts on making "nats" driver commit (ACK) messages as fast as possible when micro-batch is added to Delta. This operation must be close to instant. If during your testing you have time to notice that batch is saved and stop application (I assume we are talking at least seconds here) then smth is wrong. Btw, we use Kafka (which look very similar to NATS) and do not have such problem.

Comment: Actually while testing, first I stop the spark app and then check last batch that was saved to Delta. So app might be trying to ACK messages that were processed and saved to Delta ASAP only . However in this case maybe just before ACK was sent back to NATS, app is getting shutting down.